# Update itunes owner Email in RSS feed

Tags: rss, podcast, itunes-app

We have generated one RSS feed and submitted to itunes few months ago. Now we realised we have added the wrong email. So can we update the email id in our rss feed? If we update in our rss feed, Do we need to submit again? please let us know about this. Thank you.

```
<itunes:owner>

<itunes:name>FeedForAll</itunes:name>

<itunes:email>abc@abc.com</itunes:email>

</itunes:owner>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet from [Apples's doco on podcast rss feeds](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390)...

> `<itunes:owner>`
>
> The podcast owner contact information.
>
> Include the email address of the owner in a nested `<itunes:email>` tag
>   and the name of the owner in a nested `<itunes:name>` tag.
>
> Note: The `<itunes:owner>` tag information is for administrative
>   communication about the podcast and isn’t displayed in Apple Podcasts.
>   Please make sure the email address is active and monitored.

Once Apple has verified the ownership and quality of your rss feed (i.e. through [the podcast submission process](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcd88ea40b9)) then your podcast is active in their directory.

From that point you are free to update your feed however you like, as long as your updates continue to conform to [Apple's rss feed requirements](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390).

In this case, if you update the value of the `<itunes:email>` then the change should automatically be picked up during the next feed refresh. i.e. you shouldn't need to resubmit.

Note: you should still use a valid email address in that tag so that people can contact you if there are issues with your feed, or they genuinely want to get in touch, etc. If you are worried about spam, then perhaps use an email address that different from your day-to-day address. i.e. One that you can access/check when you need to but that won't bother you if it gets hit with spam. You can  drop in there and check it/clear it out occasionally as needed.

Also worth thinking about. Other podcast directories sometimes rely on email addresses in rss feeds in order to verify ownership. E.g. [this is how Google uses it](https://support.google.com/googleplay/podcasts/answer/6260341?hl=en)...

> Step 3: Verify ownership
>
> After you’ve submitted your RSS feed, review the email address used to
>   verify ownership of your podcast. To verify that you own the podcast
>   content you’re adding, you need to have an email address in the
>   `<googleplay:email>` or `<itunes:email>` field of your podcast’s RSS feed.
>   Click Send verification code. Check the email account listed for your
>   verification email. Visit the link included in the email to complete
>   the verification process.